# return final row of dataframe - recurring variable names

Tags: r, extract, aggregate, plyr

I want to return the final row for each subsection of a dataframe. I'm aware of the ddply and aggregate functions, but they are not giving the expected output in this case, as the column by which I split the data has recurring names.

For example, in df:

```
year <- rep(c(2011, 2012, 2013), each=12)
season <- rep(c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter"), each=3)
allseason <- rep(season, 3)
temp <- rnorm(36, mean = 61, sd = 10)
df <- data.frame(year, allseason, temp)
```

I want to return the final temp reading at the end of every season. When I run either

```
final1 <- aggregate(df, list(df$allseason), tail, 1)
```

or

```
final2 <- ddply(df, .(allseason), tail, 1)
```

I get only the final 4 seasons (i.e. those of 2013). The function seems to stop there and does not go back to previous years/seasons. My intended output is a data frame with 12 rows * 3 columns.

All help appreciated!

*I notice that in the df created here, the allseasons column is designated as a factor with 4 levels, whereas this is not the case in my original dataframe.

Comment: Regarding your note, read `?data.frame`, which explains that you can specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. For reproducibility, this example should also have a `set.seed` line at the beginning due to use of random number generation.

Comment: Ooops, forgot to add the set.seed. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ddply code, you only forgot to also group by year:

With `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(year, allseason), tail, 1)
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(year, allseason) %>%
  do(tail(.,1))
```

Or if you want a base R alternative you can use `ave`:

```
df[with(df, ave(year, list(year, allseason), FUN = seq_along)) == 3,]
```

Result:

```
#   year allseason     temp
#1  2011    Autumn 63.40626
#2  2011    Spring 59.69441
#3  2011    Summer 42.33252
#4  2011    Winter 79.10926
#5  2012    Autumn 63.14974
#6  2012    Spring 60.32811
#7  2012    Summer 67.57364
#8  2012    Winter 61.39100
#9  2013    Autumn 50.30501
#10 2013    Spring 61.43044
#11 2013    Summer 55.16605
#12 2013    Winter 69.37070
```

Note that the output will contain the same rows in each case, only the ordering may differ.

Comment: Thanks (again) beginneR. That was a fairly evident mistake on my behalf and what you provided is the answer to the question posed......However, in my original data frame, the date is in dd/mm/yy format, so the output is not exactly what I want. I suppose I can create another column to extract out only the year.......

Comment: If you date column is formatted as `Date`, you could either create an additional column as you said with `transform(df, YearOnly = format(date, "%Y"))` or you could use that transformation in the `ddply` call like this: `ddply(df, .(format(date, "%Y"), allseason), tail, 1)`. Does that work for your actual data? If it's not yet formatted as `Date`, use `as.Date(as.character(date), format = "%d/%m/%y")` where I used only `date`.

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks again. Had to format my date column but was going to have to do that at some stage anyways.

Answer (score 3):

And just to add to @beginneR's answer, your `aggregate` solution should look like:

```
aggregate(temp ~ allseason + year, data = df, tail, 1)
# or:
with(df, aggregate(temp, list(allseason, year), tail, 1))
```

Result:

```
   allseason year     temp
1     Autumn 2011 64.51539
2     Spring 2011 45.14341
3     Summer 2011 62.29240
4     Winter 2011 47.97461
5     Autumn 2012 43.16781
6     Spring 2012 80.02419
7     Summer 2012 72.31149
8     Winter 2012 45.58344
9     Autumn 2013 55.92607
10    Spring 2013 52.06778
11    Summer 2013 51.01308
12    Winter 2013 53.22452
```